# ImportError: No module named 'yaml'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyyaml

I have one script in which I am trying to execute

```
python3 env/common_config/add_imagepullsecret.py
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
 [root@kevin]# python3 env/common_config/add_imagepullsecret.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "env/common_config/add_imagepullsecret.py", line 4, in <module>
 import yaml
 ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
 [root@kevin]# pip3 install pyyaml
 Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages 
 (3.12)
 [root@kevin]#
```

PyYAML is already installed in the machine:

```
 [root@bhimsvm31 k8s]# pip3 install pyyaml
 Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages 
 (3.12)
 [root@bhimsvm31 k8s]#
```

How can I get this script to import PyYAML?

Answer (score 292):

```
pip install pyyaml
```

This should serve the purpose

Comment: In case others run into the issue of "command 'pip' not found" - I had to modify this to pip3 install pyyaml

Comment: alternatively, use `pipenv` - it's incredible now

Comment: pip install --upgrade pip and then pip install pyyaml

Answer (score 25):

Solution 1: install python 3.6(or use `pyenv` to manage py version) and ln python3 to it

```
export $PYPATH=`which python3`
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
tar -Jxf Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.5/
./configure && make && make altinstall
rm $PYPATH
ln -s `which python3.6` $PYPATH
python3 -m pip install pyyaml
python3 env/common_config/add_imagepullsecret.py
```

Solution 2: use virtualenv (or `python -m venv`)

```
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv --python=python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pyyaml
python env/common_config/add_imagepullsecret.py
```

Solution 3: use `python-poetry` or `pipenv`

https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Answer (score 12):

In case of using [conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyyaml), you can :

```
 conda install -c anaconda pyyaml
```

Answer (score 9):

It is best practice of a developer to create a virtualenv for every project they create.This helps you to maintain the dependencies isolated from the root config of the system

**Installing virtualenv**

```
cd /*desired*/
mkdir myProject
pip install virtualenv -p python3 . #For python 3
pip install virtualenv -p python2 . #For python 2
pip install pyyaml

pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

After this you will be able to see a text doc containing all the dependencies you have installed in the virtualenv.

Cheers
:)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here arises from the fact that you have downloaded, compiled and installed a (newer) version of `python3`, on a machine that has an older `python3` installed by the package manager. The latter has and associated `pip3` the former does not. You can verify this by doing `/usr/local/bin/python3 --version` and `/usr/bin/python3 --version`

Because of that, what happens when you do `pip3 install pyyaml` is to add the PyYAML package to the old Python3. When you do:

```
/usr/bin/python3 env/common_config/add_imagepullsecret.py
```

things should work, unless you rely on some feature of the newer `python3`.

A  more structural solution is [to install `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for the newer `python3` and use that to install PyYAML.

A more structural solution, is to never install such additional `python3` in your path, but e.g. in `/opt/python/3.7.0`, use `virtualenv -p /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python /opt/util/yourutil`, install every package with 
`/opt/util/yourutil/bin/pip3 install package_name` and then do:

```
/opt/util/yourutil/bin/python env/common_config/add_imagepullsecret.py
```

to run your program. With a few supporting scripts/functions/aliases/links, this can be done very efficiently without polluting the systempython3` "install space" nor your PATH.

Comment: I had a similar situation where package manager install python2.7 and I then installed python3.8 and was using python3.8 with `python3` command whenever needed. VS Code was giving me an error so I started to look into it and realized that I have both versions installed. Removed `python2.7` and then had to link `/usr/local/bin/python3` with `/usr/bin/python3` by running `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3`

Answer (score 5):

Try the follwoing:
1. uninstall python-yaml and its dependencies.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python3-yaml
$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3-yaml
```

Purging your config/data too.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge python3-yaml
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3-yaml
```

2. Install pyyaml

   $ sudo pip3 install pyyaml

this worked for me.

Comment: Why? What is going on here?

Comment: python3-yaml is a deep dependency on a number of platforms - do this with caution.

Answer (score 3):

On mac, I had to do this

```
python3 -m pip install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was caused by "#! /usr/bin/env python" in a bash script.
even with /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin at the start of my PATH, env didn't find v 3.8, but instead defaulted to v 2.7 from /usr/bin, which didn't have PyYAML.

My solution was to modify the script to call python3 explicitly, but you could also put an symbolic link in the 3.8 bin directory so it finds python.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same (or similar) problem. You can see in initial description posted by "Neeraj" that "pyyaml" was **already installed**.
In my case the problem was in the fact that I had two python versions. So, "python" command was related to one and "py" to another one version. I find out this by

```
C:\Program Files\Python310>py --version
Python 3.12.1
C:\Program Files\Python310>python --version
Python 3.10.1
```

So, my installation of "pyyaml" module was executed in wrong environment. To clarify: the previous command

```
python -m pip install pyyaml
```

dindn't have any effect, meanwhile the solution was in:

```
py -m pip install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using a virtual environment and get this error, just deleting venv directory and reinstalling fixed things for me.

```
virtualenv --python=python3.8 .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt # or just: pip install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using pre-commit installed view brew on macos), the issue was that pyyaml was not linked, although it was installed.

To fix, I had to force linking:

```
brew link --overwrite pyyaml
```

Comment: This worked for me +1 thanks. `python3 -m pip install pyyaml` (higher voted) didn't work. macOS M1 Pro, Sanoma, brew 4.2.9, python 3.12.2

Answer (score 0):

For me, this solved my issue in Ubuntu 20 (with ROS noetic installed):

```
sudo apt install python-yaml
```

----- Updates -----

I had another issue for `No module named 'rospkg'`, but it was also installed already. This is eventually an issue about env path. What solved my problem fundamentally is the following.

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```